# create formatted list of times to display

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a list of times that the user can select in 24 hour format. Below is an example.

Start with:
01:00 AM
01:30 AM
02:00 AM ...

Ends with:
11:30 PM 00:00 AM 00:30 AM ...

I created a method as follows, but I can't get the result above.

```
  buildInitialHours() {

    const hourList: any[] = [];
    let hourObj = { hour: 0, minute: 0, label: '' };

    for (let count = 0; count < 48; count++) {
      hourObj.hour += 1;
      hourObj.minute += 30;
      hourObj.minute = hourObj.minute == 60 ? 30 : 30;
      hourObj.label = `${hourObj.hour}:${hourObj.minute}`;
      hourList.push(Object.assign({}, hourObj));
    }

    this.initialHours = hourList;
  }
```

Comment: You can use [Angular Moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment)

Comment: Moment tends to be rather big. It’s not modular. Use date-fns.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can just populate the list with dates and then use angular date pipe to format it when you display it. Use date-fns or moment to work with the dates

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
  buildInitialHours() {

    let hourList: Date[] = [];
    const data = moment();

    for (let count = 0; count < 48; count++) {
      let lastHour = hourList[hourList.length - 1];

      if (!lastHour) {
        data.set({ hour: 0, minute: 0, seconds: 0 });
        hourList.push(data.toDate());
        continue;
      }

      const newHour = lastHour.getMinutes() == 30 ? lastHour.getHours() + 1 : lastHour.getHours();
      const newMinutes = lastHour.getMinutes() == 0 ? 30 : 0;
      const obj = { hour: newHour, minutes: newMinutes, seconds: 0 };
      lastHour = moment(lastHour).set(obj).toDate();
      hourList.push(lastHour);

    }

    this.initialHours = hourList;
  }
```